# Column space of a matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

<sub>Well, my question is gonna be a bit of idiotic, I think.</sub>

---

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$  matrix. We know the column space of $A$, which we denote by $C(A)$, is the set of non-zero vectors$\{\overrightarrow{b_1},\overrightarrow{b_2},...,\overrightarrow{b_n}\}$ such that $A\overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{b}$. And the nullspace, which we denote by $N(A)$, is the set of non-zero vectors $\{\overrightarrow{x_1},\overrightarrow{x_2},...,\overrightarrow{x_n}\}$ such that $A\overrightarrow{x}=0$. Can anyone tell me why $C(A)$ isn't made of the $\overrightarrow{x}$'s from $A\overrightarrow{x}=\overrightarrow{b}$?

Comment: Well, for one, dimensions disagree in the proposed relationship. Specifically, if $A$ is $n\times m$ then $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $C(A)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $N(A)\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ (assuming this is taking place over the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. Null($A$) is the set of vectors that get mapped to the the zero vector by the transformation $T : \overrightarrow{x}\mapsto A\overrightarrow{x}$.

Therefore if the homogeneous equation for $A$, $A\overrightarrow{x}=0$ has a nontivial solution, or in other words, for every non-zero vector $\overrightarrow{x}$, if
\begin{align}
x_1\overrightarrow{a_1}+x_2\overrightarrow{a_2}+...+x_n\overrightarrow{a_n}=0
\end{align}
Then $x \in Null(A)$

$Col(A)$ consists of all $\overrightarrow{b}$ s.t. $\overrightarrow{b}$ can be written as a linear combination of the columns of $A$. Therefore, if $\overrightarrow{b}$ can be written as
\begin{align}
x_1\overrightarrow{a_1}+x_2\overrightarrow{a_2}+...+x_n\overrightarrow{a_n}=\overrightarrow{b}
\end{align}
For some $\overrightarrow{x}$ with entries $\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$, not all zero,  that act as scalars on the columns of $A$ (by the definition of $A\overrightarrow{x}$), then $\overrightarrow{b} \in Span\{a_1,a_2,a_n\}, b\in Col(A)$.